# cut command to remove seconds from time. shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, cut

Lets say we got date and time to a log in the format of

```
2022-05-18-11:57:140100
```

I need to remove seconds from this time. It means the final output should be like

```
 2022-05-18-11:57
```

I tried the following

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | rev | cut -d/ -f6- | rev`:"
```

this was not successful and I have no idea how this cut command works. can anybody explain. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` you can simply do it like following. Simple explanation would be, set `FS` and `OFS` as `:` and then in main block of `awk` program decrease `NF` with 1 and print the line.

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} NF--'
```

***2nd solution:*** In any `awk` using `awk`'s `match` function please try following.

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | awk 'match($0,/.*:/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `sed`'s capability of capturing groups(keep values in temp buffer) please try following code.

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | sed -E 's/(^[^:]*):([^:]*):.*/\1:\2/'
```

***4th solution(OP's efforts FIX):*** Fixing OP's efforts using `rev` + `cut` + `rev` combination here.

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | rev | cut -d':' -f2- | rev
```

Comment: Thanks @ravinderSingh both works. but first one gives echo 2 times

Comment: @CodeWithBanchi, sorry there was typo fixed it now.

Comment: can you tell me what -f2- means

Comment: @CodeWithBanchi, means print everything till end of value starting from 2nd field where delimiter is made as `:`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in bash shell also:

```bash
s='2022-05-18-11:57:140100'
echo "${s%:*}"

2022-05-18-11:57

# or else use cut
cut -d: -f1-2 <<< "$s"
2022-05-18-11:57

# or sed
sed 's/:[^:]*$//' <<< "$s"
2022-05-18-11:57
```

Answer (score 0):

any one of these 5 solutions should work for `gawk`, `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, and `macos nawk` :

```
echo "2022-05-18-11:57:140100" | 

      mawk2   NF=NF   FS=':[^:]*$' OFS=
   or
      gawk -- --NF    FS=':[^:]*$'
   or 
      gawk    NF--    FS=':[^:]*$'
   or
      nawk    NF=1    FS=':[^:]*$'
   or
      mawk  '$!_=$!_' FS=':[^:]*$'

2022-05-18-11:57
```

The most compacted version would be like

```
mawk -F':[^:]*$' NF--
```